# Window grid keyboard shortcuts on Gnome Wayland?

Tags: window-manager, wayland, tiling

I want to be able to position my windows top, bottom - left, right, occupying a quarter of the screen. Compiz offers a utility for this under Window Grid, but Compiz is for X. What is the best method to quickly position my windows using key combinations? eg

```
ctrl + alt + 7
```

For top-left placement

Comment: so the window if on the left border has to be 1/4th the width of the screen, for example?

Comment: I do not need to be able to tile in the way you are describing, I need to tile in the corners such that the height and width of the windows are 1/2 the height and width of the screen respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more searching I have found what I need. gTile offers grid tiling with configurable keyboard shortcuts for any position and size of tiling. Can be obtained from Ubuntu Software Centre, to configure keyboard shortcuts go to Ubuntu Software -> Installed -> Extension Settings. Configure presets under "Resize Presets" and configure keyboard shortcuts under "Accelerators"

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is :

1. <kbd>***⊞***</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> for maximising the window
2. <kbd>***⊞***</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> for minimizing the window (back to minimized proportions)
3. <kbd>***⊞***</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for moving the window to left hand side (half of width)
4. <kbd>***⊞***</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> for moving the window to right hand side (half of width)

Comment: Wrote that already in my answer. Moreover, user also refers to quarter tiling.

Comment: I am aware of these, but I need quarter tiling as mentioned above

Comment: @Rob I specifically asked if you would need it, you said no, look at your comments on your question.

Comment: @tatsu ok... I said no. Why have you then proceeded to provide what I do not need? vanadium's comment is correct, I need quarter tiling.

Comment: "I do not need to be able to tile in the way you are describing, I need to tile in the corners such that the height and width of the windows are 1/2 the height and width of the screen respectively"